Restringir acceso con IP dinamica o NIC a mi web o webservice
Con el IIS estoy intentando restringir acceso a mi pagina web. Tengo una lista blanca donde solo dejo pasar la IP de la lista.
Esto solo funciona para IP estatica o fija. Si el cliente que se quiere conectar tiene una IP dinamica entonces ya no esta en la lista blanca y por lo tanto no tiene acceso.
Me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de dar acceso con el IIS a clientes con IP dinamica, habia pensado que alomejor se puede dar acceso por "numero de identificación de tarjeta de red o NIC" en este caso seria por NIC de la tarjeta del router que esta conectado al exterior.
He probado la opcion de dar acceso por DNS pero el cliente no tiene una DNS asignada a su IP externa.


Hoy la mayoría de los ISP usan NAT, por lo que el identificador de la tarjeta de red también puede ser variable, y entonces te encuentras en el mismo problema. Se me ocurre que puedes usar un servidor DNS privado o editar el archivo host de los usuarios (en windows) y utilizar un nombre de domino que no sea público. Una VPN también sería otra opción

Limitar acceso por identificación del equipo será imposible si no tienes total control sobre el mismo. Creo que una opción más fácil de mantener puede ser el clásico login y si quieres le pones una seguridad adicional como verificación multifactor o un token por software.

@Yussef te refieres a que el cliente use un servidor de DNS privado?

Claro, puedes crear un dominio con cualquier nombre "miweb.popu" y solo los que tienen configurado tu DNS entenderán a donde apunta ese nombre de dominio. En cualquier caso, la forma segura es usando una VPN

@Yussef mi pagina web o webservice ya tiene un dominio. Lo que quiero es que la pagina web sea accesible desde el exterior solo a los clientes que esten incluidos en una "lista blanca". El tema es que el cliente desde su PC puede estar conectado a una IP que no es fija
